# Removing the phosphor coating in fluorescent lamp

Tags: uv, fluorescent-lamp

Any ideas on how to remove the inner phosphor coating on the inner surface of fluorescent tube lamp turning it into a UV lamp?

Comment: Amr, from your comment: "I want to remove the coating to exactly find out by experimentation whether practical amount of UV will pass." Perhaps it will be easier to simply break the tube and perform experiments on larger shards of glass...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to open it, clean off the phosphor and then reseal it with the right pressure of mercury vapour intact.

You'd also have to replace the envelope with a different kind of glass if you wanted UVC (germicidal) 235nm light.

Basically, forget about it.

Comment: Not only for the coronavirus but you got me :)

Comment: Can't you make your answer more motivating. I was thinking of knocking the outer surface until the counting falls off ir placing it on top of shaking surface like the top of the washing machine or trunk of a car for a week or two.

Comment: no, why should an answer be more motivating? Spehro did his best to explain what needs to be done, and even went further and exactly guessed your application. He's very welcoming to you! The thing you want to do is impossible with small-scale tools, and that's a fact.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Actually he didn't guessed my application but that doesn't mean I didn't thought about it as a secondary application too and I had to give him credit with a comment & an upvote for his good answer despite his sarcasm when saying I have to open it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What are the minimum tools required to that you may answer instead of investigating others motivations and possible applications because you will fail most of the time and will only make distraction by bloating threads

Comment: @AmrBerag No "sarcasm" intended. Many of  us actually have vacuum systems capable of doing this, and argon tanks on our TIG welders for refilling, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: A historical note - this was a very bad idea in the early days of fluorescents. The first phosphors contained beryllium, and beryllium is toxic when inhaled. The result is a very nasty lung condition.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast They seem to be using Halophosphate phosphors now, warm white is given as:\$3\text {Ca}_3(\text{PO}_4)_2\cdot \text{Ca(F,Cl)}_2:\text{Sb}^{3+},\text{Mn}^{2+}\$.

Comment: @AmrBerag he answered that, basically: you need to replace both the glas tube and need to refill it with mercury vapor. The only thing you'd be able to keep would be the wiring. So, you basically need a factory for fluorescent tubes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Replacing the glass tube despite the fact its an appreciated information that I didn't knew, was based on the assumption that I want to use it as a sanitizer but that wasn't the only nor the main purpose, thus, I need to only clean the couting. There are many things you can do with UV light.

Comment: @AmrBerag the glass in fluorescent tubes is less transparent to all UV than to visible light, on purpose. So yes, you need to replace the glass.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "the glass in fluorescent tubes is less transparent to all UV" Less than what? thats a relative sentence. And you may also know that all those Chinese manufacturers dont respect regulations or what you read in books and articles not even 1% of them

Comment: @AmrBerag less transparent than UV-transparent glass that you have to use in a UV lamp. Come on, it's not that hard to research how a fluorescent lamp works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Bingo, you finally unintentionally got close to guessing it, I want to remove the couting to exactly find out by experimentation whether practical amount of UV will pass.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are complaining about me not searching while if  you search you will find out about the health concerns of UV from flourocent lighting but question is: would it be practical after the couting is removed

Comment: @AmrBerag just a couple comments ago you complained about "less transparent" being a relative term. Now you complain about "less transparent" not being the same as "opaque". OK.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly, because I'm the one who is asking and you are the one who pretended to know just because, Without providing numbers nor references. Now opacity and transparency are  expressed in percentage and wavelength is measured in nm in this context but you can use other words like practical or not. If you read Mr. Pefhany's answer it says replacement of the tube is needed for certain wavelength range (235nm) and while I was trying to start conversation with him because he seems to know alot you jumped as if some kid is about to hit your younger brother in a kindergarten

Comment: you could try using a laser

Comment: @jsotola How? I was thinking of resonating the tube with speakers like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tADutH-qV8A)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply a source of high-frequency ultrasound to the glass, vibrating the glass for a long time will lead to the separation of the phosphor. Then the lamp will begin to emit long-wave ultraviolet